# Zero-curvature formulation of the Camassa-Holm hierarchy

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integrable-systems

In the book of [Gesztesy and Holden](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/soliton-equations-and-their-algebrogeometric-solutions/0239D84F9561EB2BFA452BAAE4B0B686) (see the following [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/revista-matematica-iberoamericana/volume-19/issue-1/Algebro-Geometric-Solutions-of-the-Camassa-Holm-hierarchy/rmi/1049123081.full) of the same authors), they state that the Camassa-Holm hierarchy may be casted as a zero-curvature equation
\begin{align}
-V_{n,x}+\left[U,V_n\right]=0\,,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
U=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
\frac{4u-u_{xx}}{z} & 1
\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad V_n(z)=\begin{pmatrix}
-G_n(z) & F_n(z)\\
\frac{H_n(z)}{z} & G_n(z)
\end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{align}
with $z$ an arbitrary constant and $F_n$, $G_n$ and $H_n$ are functions that has to be specified. Replacing the latter matrices into the zero-curvature equation, one readily obtains the following equations
\begin{align}
F_{n,x}&=2(G_n-F_n)\,,\\
zG_{n,x}&=(4u-u_{xx})F_n-H_n\,,\\
H_{n,x}&=2H_n-2(4u-u_{xx})G_n\,.
\end{align}
The authors say that if we make the following polynomial ansatz with respect to $z$,
\begin{align}
F_n(z)=\sum_{l=0}^n f_{n-l}z^l\,,\quad G_n(z)=\sum_{l=0}^n g_{n-l}z^l\,,\quad H_n(z)=\sum_{l=0}^n h_{n-l}z^l\,,
\end{align}
it is possible to obtain the following recursive relation for $f_l$
\begin{align}
f_0=1\,,\quad f_{l,x}=-2\left(4-\partial_{xx}\right)^{-1}\left[2(4u-u_{xx})f_{l-1,x}+(4u_x-u_{xxx})f_{l-1}\right]\,,\quad l\in\mathbb{N}\,,
\end{align}
and for $g_l$ and $h_l$,
\begin{align}
g_l&=f_l+\frac{1}{2}f_{l,x}\,,\quad l\in\mathbb{N}_0\,,\\
h_l&=(4u-u_{xx})f_l-g_{l+1,x}\,,\quad l\in\mathbb{N}_0\,.
\end{align}
Additionally, for fixed $n$ they obtain $h_n=(4u-u_{xx})f_n$ and
\begin{align}
h_{n,x}-2h_n+2(4u-u_{xx})g_n=0\,,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}_0\,.
\end{align}
I obtained all of the previous relations, but I am not being able to obtain the one for $f_{l,x}$, namely, $f_{l,x}=-2\left(4-\partial_{xx}\right)^{-1}\left[2(4u-u_{xx})f_{l-1,x}+(4u_x-u_{xxx})f_{l-1}\right]$.